# After creating NAN category, aggregation on groupby object went wrong

Tags: python, pandas

I first create some data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"A":np.random.random_integers(1,10,10), "B":np.arange(1,11,1)})
df.A.ix[3,4] = np.nan
```

Then I got a pd dataframe with Nans

```
    A   B
0   7   1
1   1   2
2   3   3
3   NaN 4
4   NaN 5
5   9   6
6   2   7
7   10  8
8   6   9
9   6   10
```

I try to group column A using pd.cut function add use aggregation functions on each group

```
bin_S = pd.cut(df.A, [-math.inf, 3,5,8,9, math.inf],right= False)
df.groupby(bin_S).agg("count")
```

But the Nan values are not grouped( no Nan category)

```
            A   B
A       
[-inf, 3)   2   2
[3, 5)      1   1
[5, 8)      3   3
[8, 9)      0   0
[9, inf)    2   2
```

Then I tried to add a new category called "Missing" by:

```
bin_S.cat.add_categories("Missing", inplace = True) 
bin_S.fillna(value = "Missing", inplace = True
```

The binning series looks fine. However, the groupby aggregation is not what I expected.

```
df.groupby(bin_S).agg("count")
```

Result is,

```
            A   B
A       
[-inf, 3)   2   2
[3, 5)      1   1
[5, 8)      3   3
[8, 9)      0   0
[9, inf)    2   2
Missing     0   2
```

I am expecting column A and column B to be exactly the same. Why they are different on row "Missing"? The real problem  involves more complicated operation on each group. This issue really bothers me since grouping Nan values might be unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'count'` is going to skip `NaN`.  You can use `'size'`

```
df.groupby(bin_S).agg(["size"])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. df.groupby(bin_S).agg(np.size). I changed a little , so there is no multi-level index in the outupt